# conditional nginx rewrite rule that exclude redirecting to www if www is already in request

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am using nginx for managing multiple domains for reverse proxy.

I want to redirect all http request to https

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

However, I am not sure how can I make it work for rewriting non www requests to redirect to www in generic way excluding rewriting those requests that already has www in requests as if I just modify below rule it creates problem when someone write as [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) it
rewrite to [www.www.domain.com](http://www.www.domain.com)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
}
```

Please check this image to understand the issue.
[image: redirecting to www.www.domain]

So I need to have some condition that handles that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic approach, you can use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive (should be placed **outside** the `server` block):

```
map $host $basename {
    ~^www\.(.+)  $1;
    default      $host;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$basename$request_uri;
}
```

**Update 1**

It's look I misread your question (you need to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com` but my answer does an opposite thing), please try the following:

```
map $host $basename {
    ~^www\.(.+)  $host;
    default      www.$host;
}
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$basename$request_uri;
}
```

**Update 2**

OP asks an additional question:

> Is there a way to exclude specific sub domain like `static.example.com` which I don't want to rewrite to `www.static.example.com`?

Yes, rewrite of `static` subdomain can be prevented with the following `map` block:

```
map $host $basename {
    ~^(?:www|static)\..+  $host;
    default               www.$host;
}
```

If you want to prevent rewrite of any three-component domain name, you can use

```
map $host $basename {
    ~[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+  $host;
    default               www.$host;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried with this, however this does not rewrite domain.com to www.domain.com

Comment: As I understand your question, you're want an opposite, rewrite www.domain.com to domain.com?

Comment: thanks, I have tried this. But it seems that http://example.com rewrites to https://www.example.com, but https://example.com fails to rewrites to https://www.example.com. Any idea what can help here?

Comment: Also, is there a way to exclude specific sub domain like static.example.com which I don't want to rewrite to www.static.example.com ?

Comment: Rewriting `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` where `example.com` addresses multiple domains (e.g. `domain1.com`, `domain2.com` etc.) is a more complex task. If you want to do it with the only one `server` block, you'll need a certificate that matches any of those domains. Though it is [possible](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#:~:text=If%20you%E2%80%99re%20getting%20a%20certificate%20for%20many%20domains%20at%20once), you'll need to list all the domains in the `certbot` command line. Is this acceptable for you?

Comment: yes, we already do that using certbot command line and has certificate for each domains.

Comment: Do you mean you already have **one** certificate that has every of your domain names listed in its SAN (subject alternate name) list like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553302/add-an-id-in-the-ssl-certificate-subject-field)? Or you have multiply certificates for multiply domains?

Comment: Answer to your second question given as "Update 2" of the answer.

Comment: I have multiple certificate. One for each domain.

Comment: I see "Update 1" is same where `http://example.com` rewrites to `https://www.example.com`, but `https://example.com` fails to rewrites to `https://www.example.com`.

Comment: have you checked it?

Answer (score 1):

**Non-www to www & https redirect**

If I understand correctly, then you want to force non www to www. And you want to force all requests to https. This config code checks if the `$host` start with `"www."` or not. If it does not, then nginx will add `"www."` before the `$host` then return the correct https location. It will work with subdomains as well.

```
server {
  if ($host !~* ^www\.) {
    # if host name starts with (case insensitive) "www."
    return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
  }
  if ($host ~* ^www\. ) {
    # if host name doesn't start with (case insensitive) "www."
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 404;
}
```

**Possibly better way with Certbot**

You can automatically produce the code you need by using [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/). It will also help you manage certificates a lot and automate renewal. But Certbot will not change non-www to www, you'll have to edit auto-generated config to look like the config above. The other difference is that you will be expected to have different config blocks/files per domain, but not sure if necessary. This is what the default config looks like per domain.

```
server {
  if ($host = www.yourdomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


  if ($host = yourdomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I think it's best practice to separate the config files for each domain and subdomain and use the default Certbot format until you have understood Nginx more. This way you can disable the redirect of non-www to www very easily. The default code above from Certbot, would be what you would put when you don't want to redirect in that case. Long term this makes more sense to me, but I understand when users are more comfortable with www or other parts of the website might need the www.

Comment: shouldn't the second conditional rule have `https://www.$host$request_uri` instead of `https://$host$request_uri`? Also, see `https://example.com` does not redirect to `https://www.example.com`. Pls help

Comment: I tested it. The first block works. You can just replace your server config block with that one. `www.` is part of the `$host` so it doesn't need to be added to the return statement.

The second code block would need you to fix other parts of the code. Make sure you read everything i wrote.

Comment: Sure. I didn't get what you mean by 'The second code block would need you to fix other parts of the code'?

Comment: You can't use the second code block to get your desired outcome. I explained what it does and you should learn more about why it might be better on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com me.yourdomain.com;
        return 301 https://yourdomain.com$request_uri;
       }
```

this will rewrite all 3 domains to https://yourdomain.com

I am not sure about my answer. I am not able to test this now.
please try this and comment back

Comment: I am using multiple domain names, and that prevents me to specify domain in rule. I need something that is generic. Moreover, this rule will not solve the purpose as it is not going to rewrite to www domain.

Comment: server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com me.yourdomain.com;
add your multiple domains here 
and change this 
"return 301 https://www.yourdomain.com$request_uri;"

Comment: thanks for your help. what happens is: when visitor enter www.domain.com, it redirects to www.www.domain.com. That's what I need to fix. Moreover, there are more than one domains so need rule that does not require me to write specific domain for each domain entry.